# How to print files name from... to

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have to print the content of specify files from list of file as below. Date in the begining files name is changeable and the part "_lol_lol.txt" is constans.

```
ls
2015-01-03_lol_lol.txt
2015-01-24_lol_lol.txt
...
2015-10-23_lol_lol.txt
2015-10-24_lol_lol.txt
...
2015-11-14_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-15_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-16_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-17_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-18_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-19_lol_lol.txt
2015-11-20_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-21_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-22_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-23_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-24_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-25_lol_lol.txt
```

Every file contains some data, for the purpose of case:

```
cat 2015-01-03_lol_lol.txt
2015-01-03
cat 2015-01-24_lol_lol.txt
2015-01-24
...
cat 2015-10-23_lol_lol.txt
2015-10-23
cat 2015-10-24_lol_lol.txt
2015-10-24
...
cat 2015-11-14_lol_lol.txt
2015-11-14
cat 2015-11-15_lol_lol.txt
2015-11-15
...
cat 2015-11-25_lol_lol.txt
2015-11-25
```

And I want to print content of fles from fange "from" "to" and both "from" and "to" is variable (defined by user, depending on the needs):

```
2015-11-15_lol_lol.txt
2015-11-16_lol_lol.txt 
2015-11-17_lol_lol.txt
```

Expectet result:

```
2015-11-15
2015-11-16
2015-11-17
```

But when I use command:

```
for i in {"2015-11-15".."2015-11-17"};do echo  $i_lol_lol.txt ;done
```

Bash returns:

```
{2015-11-15..2015-11-17}.txt
```

Because like @karoshi if I use "-" whole expression is recognize like string.

I tried:

```
y1=2015;
y2=2015;
m1=11;
m2=11;
d=15
z=17

#for i in {${y1}..${y2}}; do
   for j in {${m1}..${m2}}; do
           for k in {${d1}..${d2}}; do
                   cat ${i}-${j}-${k}_lol_lol.txt
           done
   done
done`
```

But result is simmilar.

Could you help?

Comment: What sort of ranges do you need to support here? What about if a given file in the range doesn't exist?

Comment: If you want to print content files, you probably want to say `cat`, not `echo`.

Comment: @fedorqui you're right. i want to use `cat` not `echo`.

@Etan Reisner ranges is whole year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through given months and days, there is way to use the `{..}` syntax. Why? Because this expansion occurs even before variables are being checked, so that no variables can be stored there.

Instead, use `seq`, which does admit variables.

```
$ a=12
$ b=23
$ for i in $(seq $a $b); do echo "$i"; done
12
13
...
21
22
23
```

In this case, you may want to say:

- Get `$min_month` and `$max_month`
- Get `$min_day` and `$max_day`

And then perform a double loop:

```
for month in $(seq "$min_month" "$max_month");
do
    for day in $(seq "$min_day""$max_day");
    do
         cat 2015-${month}-${day}_lol_lol.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: Don't even need to do that much, `for i in 2015-11-1{5,6,7}_lol_lol.txt;do echo $i;done`

Comment: This data range is only example. Because in this case i have to `cat` dates from 11-15 to 11-17 but for two days i will have to `cat` dates from 11-17 to 11-19.

Comment: @DamianSilkowski then update your question with a more detailed example please!

Comment: @fedorqui done. I hope my description is enough for you now.

Comment: @DamianSilkowski it would be better to update explaining the logic of it ("I want to print those whose name contains X and Y") instead of pasting a full list of them. Could you edit and show that?

Comment: @fedorqui I hope now is better.

Comment: @DamianSilkowski it indeed is. Please check my completely new approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just try

```
for i in {15..17};do echo  2015-11-${i}_lol_lol.txt ;done
```

The completion doesn't work with the '-' included, because bash doesn't recognize it as an integer.

Comment: So I have to change date format from 2015-11-15 to 2015.11.15. But what  happens if the month changed, i.e. I will have to `cat` files from 2015-11-29 to 2015-12-03?